# How to use regex to replace image names to img tags?

Tags: php, regex

Say I need to replace any of the following:

`{{image.jpg}}` or `{{any-othEr_Fil3.JPG}}`

To:

`<img src="image.jpg" alt="" />` or `<img src="any-othEr_Fil3.JPG" alt="" />` respectively using PHP and regex.

What would be the scheme?

I've been trying, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick fix

To match the characters in between the `{{` and the `}}` we should use `(.+?)`.  The `.` means to match any character including white space.  I allowed for this since `file name.jpg` is a valid file name (if you don't want white space replace `.+?` with `\S+?`).  The `+` means that there needs to be more than one character for the match to happen.  The `?` means that the regexp will try to match as few characters as possible.  So then if we use the regexp `{{(.+?)}}` the captured characters will be those in between the nearest sets of `{{` and `}}`.  For example:

```
$string = '{{image.jpg}} or {{any-othEr_Fil3.JPG}}';
echo preg_replace_callback('/{{(.+?)}}/', function($matches) {
    return sprintf('<img src="%s" alt="" />', $matches[1]);
}, $string);
```

Will echo

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" /> or <img src="any-othEr_Fil3.JPG" alt="" />
```

## Getting fancy

The regexp `/{{\s*(.+?\.(?:jpg|png|gif|jpeg))\s*}}/i` will match any image file names (with jpg, png, gif, or jpeg file extensions) in between sets of `{{` and `}}` allowing for space in between  the curly brackets and the file name.  For example :

```
$string = "{{image.jpg}} or {{ any-othEr_Fil3.JPG }} \n"
        . "{{ with_spaces.jpeg }} and {{ this_is_not_an_image_so }} don't replace me \n"
        . "{{ demonstrating spaces in file names.png }}";

$regexp = '/{{\s*(.+?\.(?:jpg|png|gif|jpeg))\s*}}/i';

echo preg_replace_callback($regexp, function($matches) {
    return sprintf('<img src="%s" alt="" />', $matches[1]);
}, $string);
```

Will echo

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" /> or <img src="any-othEr_Fil3.JPG" alt="" /> 
<img src="with_spaces.jpeg" alt="" /> and {{ this_is_not_an_image_so }} don't replace me 
<img src="demonstrating spaces in file names.png" alt="" />
```

## More Resources

[PHP preg_replace_callback documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

[The site I use to test and practice regular expressions](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The regex to match (I assume that file name does not contain `}` character - if it does contains, then there must be a scheme to escape it, which I don't know from your provided information):

```
/{{([^}]*)}}/
```

The string to replace:

```
'<img src="$1" alt="" />'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in Perl but should be similar in PHP:

From command line:

```
echo "{{image.jpg}} {{any-othEr_Fil3.JPG}}" | perl -ne '$_ =~ s/{{([^}]+)}}/&lt;img src="$1" alt="" \/&gt;/g; print $_'
```